# Map with an error bar on key in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

The problem:

I want to have a Map in java like this:

```
Map<Double,List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<Double,List<MyClass>>();
```

I want to basically group MyClass objects based on a double value.

But Key (Double) is experimental data and it has noise in it. I wish to add items to the same list even if the key is a little bit different.

For eg:

If I have `key = 1300.5` inside the map already, if the new value that I am trying to add is `newKey = 1300.7` say,

when I say `map.containsKey(newKey)` I want the map to return `true`

Also when I say `map.get(newKey)` I want it to return the corresponding list value of `key=1300.5` to which I will then add a new `MyClass`.

What have I done so far:

I created this class which would now be my key instead of `Double`

```
class NearestFreq{
    Double freq;
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("inside equals method...");
        if(Math.abs(this.freq-((NearestFreq)obj).freq)<Constants.range){
            return true;
        }
        else  {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public NearestFreq(Double freq) {
        super();
        this.freq = freq;
    }

}
```

I expected that this would then make the map assume two keys are the same if they are within the error bars. I changed my map to:

```
 Map<NearestFreq,List<MyClass>> map = new HashMap<NearestFreq,List<MyClass>();
```

But I found that the map's containsKey() call did not call NearestFreq's `.equals()` method ( `"inside equals method..."` never got printed ), which I did not understand why.

Can anyone tell me how do I accomplish this?

Comment: When you provide `equals`, you also have to provide a matching `hashCode` (especially when you want to use it it in a HashMap).  But I don't think this can work like that. All values would need to be equal to satisfy the transitive condition (you can build a long chain of very close Doubles between any two Doubles). What you could try is pre-define some buckets (for example round to nearest integer).

Comment: @Thilo The problem is that the noise would be several integers wide, it is -5<x<5 as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a **Hash**Map so map inserts call the `hashCode` method to figure out where in the map the item should go. `equals` is called only if there's a collision.

As a general rule in Java, if you override `equals` or `hashCode` you should always override the other as well to ensure that `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` if `a.equals(b)` is true.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to override the hashcode() method for my scenario? I should somehow coordinate and give the same integer for a range of keys, I don't get an idea on how would I do that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Guava's RangeMap:http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html

Comment: That looks good, let me go through that. Thanks Oliver. For now, I changed it to TreeMap and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround.

1. What I did was to change  `HashMap<>` to `TreeMap<>`
2. Implement `Comparable` interface for `NearestFreq` and
3. override the compareTo Method to:

   ```
   @Override
   public int compareTo(NearestFreq o) {
       if(Math.abs(this.freq-((NearestFreq)o).freq)<range){
           return 0;
       }
       else if((this.freq-((NearestFreq)o).freq) <0) {
           return -1;
       }
       else if((this.freq-((NearestFreq)o).freq) >0) {
           return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

and it works!

Comment: What happens if you have two keys that are very close but out of range, and then you try to get/put another key that is in the middle of those two?  I think you're going to get random results depending on the current shape of the tree.  Maybe that's ok, but something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up bkail. Yes I realised that problem. But for my case, it does not matter as the spacing in the classification I have is much higher than the noise level. But it is good for others to know if they come across this question.